# is there a way to have NOICE CANCELLATION through a secondary mic

Tags: audio-recording

is there a way to have NOICE CANCELLATION through a secondary mic ?

This will help in meetings.

I am able to detect 2 microphones through this:

I am finding answer to this:
https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-noise-cancelling-applications-that-can-produce-counter-noise-through-a-laptops-integrated-microphone

Comment: Some laptops use two microphones to do crude beam-forming to help reduce off-axis sound.  Is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SD.SE.

It's difficult to make noise cancellation work so adding a second microphone, possibly of a different type to the first, and hoping your computer will cancel noise when combining their outputs seems very unlikely to work.

You can get a noise-cancelling (N/C) microphone as a single unit. These can work but you need to be careful using them for meetings. A N/C mic usually requires the person speaking to be very close to the mic and it then cancels distant background sound.

If you use a N/C mic in a meeting the participants will typically all be some distance from the mic. The mic will treat the participants as distant sources and cancel them out.

So for a meeting you need a microphone designed for conference use. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=noise+cancelling+conference+microphone) shows some review articles on choosing conference microphones, including discussions of the different types available.